# How can I use T-Sql to search for text in Field1 anywhere in Table1 and link the resulting rows?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have `TableA(PID, Searchforthistext, TextToBeSearched)` with the following data

```
PID,SearchforthisText,TextToBeSearched
1,'have a nice day','I hope you have a nice day'
2,'having a bad day','I am having a bad day because of the wheather'
3,'it is a wonderful day','I hope you have a nice day because it is a wonderful day'
4,'because of the wheather','I am sorry your day is bad because of the wheather'
5,'Goodby for now','I will have a nice day but goodby for now'
```

I need to be able to search for the text and join the PID number for the records that hit, so for example I need the results from above to give me:

```
PIDSearched, PIDResults
1,1
1,3
1,5
2,2
2,4
3,3
4,2
4,4
5,5
```

I have tried to find the position of the text and then use substring and self join functions, but I cannot get an effecient set of queries to work.  Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: How did you end up with a schema that has search terms in the same record as a single search result?

Comment: You should post what you've tried so far.

Comment: I can't imagine anything will be very efficient. This is a O(n^2) problem, as you need to search *each pattern* in the table against *each phrase*.

Answer (score 1):

As djacobson points out, there seems to be a serious problem with your schema. That said, this should technically do what you want. Performance may be an issue:

```
SELECT
    T2.pid AS pid_searched,
    T1.pid AS pid_results
FROM
    My_Table T1
INNER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    T2.text_to_be_searched LIKE '%' + T1.search_for_this_text  + '%'
```

Comment: I compared your filter condition against mine and was surprised to find out that `LIKE '%<some_value>%'` performs **much better** than using `CHARINDEX`. I'm leaving mine as it is, but I was always told that using a wildcard on both sides of an input will perform badly.

Comment: @Yuck - It will perform badly in that it can't use an index on the column. It's just that CHARINDEX performs even worse :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this:

```
SELECT * INTO #TableA
FROM (
    SELECT 1 PID,'have a nice day' SearchforthisText,'I hope you have a nice day' TextToBeSearched
    UNION SELECT
    2,'having a bad day','I am having a bad day because of the wheather'
    UNION SELECT
    3,'it is a wonderful day','I hope you have a nice day because it is a wonderful day'
    UNION SELECT
    4,'because of the wheather','I am sorry your day is bad because of the wheather'
    UNION SELECT
    5,'Goodby for now','I will have a nice day but goodby for now'
) X;

WITH Patterns AS (
  SELECT PID, SearchforthisText Pattern
  FROM #TableA
), Phrases AS (
  SELECT PID, TextToBeSearched Phrase
  FROM #TableA
)
SELECT Patterns.PID, Phrases.PID
FROM Patterns, Phrases
WHERE CHARINDEX(Patterns.Pattern, Phrases.Phrase) > 0;

DROP TABLE #TableA;
```

Comment: Sorry to ask a question and run, but I had a family emergency.  Based on everyone's comments, I was able to re-work my queries using another field to identify likely matches. I then used the like % + field + % in a case statement to confirm.  Thanks for the help.